# Change title bar colour on chrome packaged apps

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is it possible to change title bar style/colour on chrome packaged apps?

My app has a black menu bar of its own and the plain white chrome title bar looks bizarre above it. I'd be happy with the default OS title bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have something like this to create your main application window:

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    bounds: {
      width: 1024,
      height: 768
    }
  });
});
```

This will make a default window with a *Chrome*-style frame. In order to remove that frame from your window, you can use `frame: none` as another option of the `create` method, like this:

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    bounds: {
      width: 500,
      height: 309
    },
    frame: 'none'
  });
});
```

Comment: This is cool but now there's no minimize/maximize/close buttons. Is there any way to add them back in?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If you want them back, you have to accept the original frame appearance. As there is methods like minimize, maximize, restore, etc in `chrome.app.window` class, you can implement a title bar by yourself.

Comment: Ah interesting!  I'll look at making my own title bar. Thanks a lot

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam : Is it possible with `chrome.windows.create` method? I want to give popup like UI for window. Is it possible with extension?